# Can I self-publish in some countries and work with a publisher for another country?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing

I am creating a series of books. I'll be ready to publish the first in one month, then have about 20-30 more that will be done across the span of the next year or two.

I'd prefer to self-publish on Amazon. The problem I have is, about 30-40% of my target readership lives in a country not served by Amazon.

Can I self-publish on Amazon to reach the audience within Western nations where Amazon is popular, and then work with a publisher in that specific country, to get the book on shelves there?

Answer (score 2):

This is a legal question.
It depends what the publishers are willing to do within copyright law.
If you use amazon you would either vanity publish or self publish not trad pub. I presume you wanted a REAL publisher in the other countries.

So CAN you - yes.
But MAY you - depends on other factors.
In particular what your amazon agreement say about competing with them that way.

There are other publishers than amazon that will put your book on amazon and also reach many other channels in many more countries.   Consider publishing through one of them instead of amazon.